# Java variable not updating inside Javascript's setinterval

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Hi I am currently doing a web application where my Java code will constantly fetch data from a database and update its own static variable. I can confirm that the variable is being updated constantly when I output it in the console, however when I want to use this variable inside my Javascript function (which is inside my .jsp code), it always takes the initial value and never gets updated despite being inside a SetInterval function.

The following is the Javascript segment where I access the Java static variable.

```
function moveMarker(map,marker){

    setInterval( function(){  
        document.write(<%=DbManager.latitude%>);
    },5000);
}
```

The DbManager.latitude variable is always in it's default value despite being changed consistently when the web app is running. I look forward to any answers I can get to fix this issue, or perhaps alternatives to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: have you tried with quotes? document.write('<%=DbManager.latitude%>');

Comment: the page is sent to the browser once ... the content on the server isn't magically sent to the page in some ethereal constant stream - you need to look at AJAX ... you also need to stop using 90's javascript (document.write is never the correct thing to use)

Comment: thank you for your responses. if i may ask, how would you get a java variable via ajax onto my jsp/javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you can goahead with AJAX for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000); // 5 MS
    });     

    function ajaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/getUpdate/" ,
            success: function(result) {
                document.write(result);
            }
          }
    });
</script>
```

Call your servlet/controller from AJAX and get the updated value

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "clause")
public class ClauseController {

  @RequestMapping(value="getUpdate") 
  @ResponseBody
  public String selectClause(ModelMap model) {
  DbManager dbManager = DAO.getDbManager;     
    return "dbManager.latitude";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was more or less able to achieve what i wanted with reference to your answer. Had to further understand Ajax myself before getting it to work as intended, main with how it communicates with the servlet and stuff.